# Undifined Variable : employess

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want to show image gallery at user page

this my code from `ImageUserController`

```
function list(){
    $employees['img_user'] = ImageUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return view('ukm.index', $employees);
}
```

and this my code from `UserContoller`

```
public function list()
{
    $employees = ImageUser::all();
    $ukm    = Ukm::all();

    return view('/ukm/index', compact( 'employees', 'ukm'));
}
```

this my route

```
Route::get('/ukm/index', 'ImageUserController@list');
```

and this my code at `ukm/index.blade.php`

```
table class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($employees as $employee)
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ $employee->id }}</th>
            <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $employee->description }}</td>
            <td><img src="{{ asset('uploads/employee/' . $employee->image) }}" width="150px;" height="100px;" alt="Image"></td>
            <td><a href="/img_user/editimage/{{ $employee->id }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="/img_user/deleteimage/{{ $employee->id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

i'm getting this error : `Undefined variable: employees`

Comment: @ZainFarooq undefined array index issue and undefined variables are two different things

Comment: change `$employees['img_user'] = ImageUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();` to `$employees['employees'] = ImageUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the array to the view actually

```
return view('ukm.index')->with('employees', $employees);
```

Comment: Great... I am happy that I could help you

Answer (score 1):

In your `ImageUserController`  `list()` method,

```
function list(){
    $employees = ImageUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return view('ukm.index', compact('employees'));
}
```

Comment: i got this error : 'Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\pkl-dilo\UKM\resources\views\ukm\index.blade.php)'